# Using Arrayformula to sum columns in multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, lambda, sum, google-sheets-formula

I'm try to sum columns(F2:F) in multiple sheets.

Here's my current formula.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($A$2:$A), ,QUERY({PROPER(FLATTEN(Romar!$B$2:$B, Angelo!$B$2:$B, Ayyan!$B$2:$B, Edwin!$B$2:$B)), FLATTEN(Romar!$F$2:$F, Angelo!$F$2:$F, Ayyan!$F$2:$F, Edwin!$F$2:$F)},  "SELECT SUM(Col2) WHERE Col1 = '" & $A$2:$A & "' LABEL SUM(Col2) ''")))`

But it gives me the same result in the entire column.

[image]

I want the result to be the sum of the person in column(A2:A) each row.

[image]

Thank you!

Here's the sample sheet. The desired result should be the total amount released for the customer at A2:A.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b3bFQzaOk2z3GAUh7mDEjBCmyRgDhbf8tpNDYX60QN8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=BYROW(A2:A, LAMBDA(x, IF(ISBLANK(x),, IFERROR(
 SUM(FILTER({Romar!F:F; Angelo!F:F; Ayyan!F:F; Edwin!F:F}, 
            {Romar!B:B; Angelo!B:B; Ayyan!B:B; Edwin!B:B}=x)), 0))))
```

[image]

Comment: btw how to you type on the next row for the code inside a cell? I use CTRL+ENTER but the code returns to the previous row as soon as I switch cells.

Comment: @Oloap first click into fx bar and press CTRL+DOWNARROW then start typing the formula and whenever you need press CTRL+ENTER to initiate new line. keep in mind that fx bar remembers all your previous edits and reverts back so if you made some mistake and fx bar reverts your desired result back into the mistake then you need to change something alongside for example `SUM` to `SuM` so that your changes would apply

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
One option is to put all this into one formula, but to make it a little more easy to manage, I've set four columns, one per sheet, with this formula (Col F to J):

> =byrow($A2:$A,lambda(each,if(isblank(each),,SUMIF(Indirect(I1&"!$B$2:$B"),each,Indirect(I1&"!$F$2:$F")))))

And then, just a sum

Or just put all this in one formula (Col K):

> =byrow(A2:A,lambda(each,if(isblank(each),,SUMIF(Romar!$B$2:$B,each,Romar!$F$2:$F)+SUMIF(Angelo!$B$2:$B,each,Angelo!$F$2:$F)+SUMIF(Ayyan!$B$2:$B,each,Ayyan!$F$2:$F)+SUMIF(Edwin!$B$2:$B,each,Edwin!$F$2:$F))

---

I'm giving a potential answer, given that it would have been ideal to try it in a sample sheet. If it doesn't work, share one and I can try it ;)

> =byrow(A2:A,lambda(each,if(isblank(each),,SUMIF({Romar!$B$2:$B;Angelo!$B$2:$B;Ayyan!$B$2:$B;Edwin!$B$2:$B},each,{Romar!$F$2:$F;Angelo!$F$2:$F;Ayyan!$F$2:$F;Edwin!$F$2:$F}))))

Let me know!

Comment: It gives an error that says argument must be a range. I also added a link to a sample sheet.

Comment: It works! Thank you for your time and effort! :)